# auto moving computer in respective OU, when joined machine in to domain

Tags: active-directory, powershell, group-policy, windows-server-2016

1. we want move Computer account automatically in respective Ou when it join Domain 
   i have some Poworshell script but it is use for manual movement "redircmp ou=newcomputerou,dc=domainname,dc=com"

so what i want, anyone in IT join system in Domain and it will automatically move right OU

Comment: Are you getting an error when you run the `redircmp` command? After running the  `redircmp` command, are newly joined computers still ending up in the Computers container?

Comment: i want this automate not this way  "redircmp ou=newcomputerou,dc=domainname,dc=com "   like anyone in IT just join system in Domain and it will automatically move to respective OU  i know there would be some predefined  Name and OU but i want to know can we do this

Answer (score 1):

Schedule your powershell script.

The script must list the computers in the default "Computers" container, find the OU, move the computer.

Comment: Hi @Swisstone you got my point   but how can we do same and what would be powershell script for same

Comment: @Biren How to write the PowerShell script would be a different question, and normally what you would do is make your best effort to write the script yourself and then post questions about your script here if you run into trouble. Generally Server Fault is not about writing scripts for other people. Assuming you're a professional system administrator, it will help you today and in your career to learn to write scripts.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this Microsoft support article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/324949/redirecting-the-users-and-computers-containers-in-active-directory-dom), the use of the `redircmp` command should take effect immediately, and all computers joined to the domain after that command has been issued should land in your "newcomputerou" OU.

> 1.Log on with Domain Administrator credentials in the domain where the CN=computers container is being redirected.
>
> 2.Transition the domain to the Windows Server 2003 domain in the Active Directory Users and Computers snap-in (Dsa.msc) or in the Domains and Trusts (Domains.msc) snap-in.For more information about increasing the domain functional level, click the following article number to view the article in the Microsoft Knowledge Base:
>
> [322692  How to raise domain and forest functional levels in Windows Server 2003](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/322692)
>
> 3.Create the organizational unit container where you want computers that are created with earlier-version APIs to be located, if the desired organizational unit container does not already exist.
>
> 4.Run the Redircmp.exe file at a command prompt by using the following syntax, where container-dn is the distinguished name of the organizational unit that will become the default location for newly created computer objects that are created by down-level APIs:
>
> `redircmp container-dn container-dn`
>
> Redircmp.exe is installed in the %Systemroot%\System32 folder on Windows Server 2003-based or newer computers. For example, to change the default location for a computer that is created with earlier-version APIs such as Net User to the OU=mycomputers container in the CONTOSO.COM domain, use the following syntax:
> C:\windows\system32>redircmp ou=mycomputers,DC=contoso,dc=com

Comment: Hi @Doug Deden  this is manual task we want automate this i already have this script

Comment: You only have to do it once. There is no need to automate it.

Answer (score 0):

**Before joining in to domain we need to create object manually on the respected OU after join the client device it will get update on that object automatically.**